# Не отправляется письмо phpmailer

Tags: fetch, phpmailer

Не могу отправить письмо на почту: Cannot POST /sendmail.php. Файл sendmail.php лежит в корневой папке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

js:

```
let formData = new FormData(form);

console.log(formData);

fetch('sendmail.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

php:

```
<?php

    // Подключаем библиотеку PHPMailer
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
    
    // Создаем письмо
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->setFrom('1', '1'); // от кого (email и имя)
    $mail->addAddress('test@tes.by', '1');  // кому (email и имя)
    $mail->Subject = 'Тест';                         // тема письма
    // html текст письма
    $mail->msgHTML("<html><body>
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                    </html></body>");
    // Отправляем
    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo 'Письмо отправлено!';
    } else {
        echo 'Ошибка: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }  

?>
```

Comment: А сервер как настроен? Отдает всё, что лежит в папке?

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov, развёрнуто всё на openserver